# Preload associations of an already loaded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have an instance of ActiveRecord model and I know that I will use a lot its association, I preload them using preload or include method on an ActiveRecord::Relation : `Model.where(...).preload(:associated_model).first` .

But is there a way to preload the associations of a model, when the model is already instantiated, without reloading it ?

Let's imagine I load my model :

```
model_instance = Model.find(x)
```

then, I would expect something like :

```
model_instance.load(:associated_model)
```

With a load method that would do a query to find the associated_model and preload it, but without reloading the model_instance.

Comment: why don't you just use `model_instance.associated_model` it will load the association without reloading the model_instance. Am I missing something ?

Comment: The fact is that I want to be able to call model_instance.associated_model.method many times without it to reload the associated_model at each call.

Comment: I don't think it will reload the association after first time. you can try it in rails console . It will query database only first time and next time it will use already loaded association.

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid. You're right. I have always thought that the associated model wasn't cached after a call. Put it as an answer if you want me to accept it !

Comment: glad to hear that there is no more confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `model_instance.associated_model` will only load the association for the first time.

If we open rails console and try it there, we'll see that it has queried the database only first time and after that all the calls to associated model didn't load it from database.

Comment: A problem with this is if you have many models' associations to preload, a query will be made for the first use of each one (aka N+1 queries). See other answer using `Associations::Preloader`.

Comment: in that case, wouldn't `my_models.preload(:my_association)` work ? (you are right, in case my_models is an array and not ActiveRecord::Relation).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for an array of models with a single query (for a single one use `[my_model]` in place of `my_models`):

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(records: my_models,
  associations: [:my_association]).call
```

Note that preloads are cached, so calling the preload again will not refresh it. There are methods for clearing preloads so you can preload them again (or let them load on use). For associated collections there's the `.reset` method (e.g. `my_model.my_associations.reset`). And for `has_one`/`belongs_to` associations, Rails 7.1 will have `my_model.reset_my_association`. See [09. Allow resetting singular associations.](https://manny.codes/this-week-in-rails-wrapped-an-overview-of-rails-7-1-features-part-iii/#:%7E:text=09.%20Allow%20resetting%20singular%20associations.)